# Reinstalling OS X Lion after erasing the HD

Tags: macos, install

A friend of mine recently bought a used Macbook (I believe it's the model before the last Macbook model from 2011). It had OSX Lion installed. I rebooted the system, held down Command + R and used Disc Utilities to to wipe it out. When I went to reinstall Lion, I get an error say that the item is not available and to try again later. Of course, trying again later has done me no good.

Any ideas? I've read elsewhere online that this is a common problem but have not found any solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can purchase Lion at Apple on a DVD: https://www.apple.com/shop/product/D6377Z/A/os-x-mountain-lion I guess that is the only legal way to install Lion on a clean Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Use Cmd/R at startup & select Internet Recovery - that should use an online recovery method & restore the OS that the machine originally shipped with. (See [About OS X Recovery](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4718).)

> Newer Macs include the ability to start up directly from an Internet-based version OS X Recovery. Your Mac automatically uses this feature when the Recovery System on the startup drive isn't available. For example, if your startup drive encounters an issue, or if your startup drive has been replaced or erased. Internet Recovery lets you start your Mac directly from Apple's servers. Starting up from this system performs a quick test of your memory and hard drive to check for hardware issues.
>
> Internet Recovery initially asks you to select a Wi-Fi network and enter a network password when needed. Next, Internet Recovery downloads and starts from a Recovery System image. From there, you are offered the same utilities and options as the Recovery System on a startup drive.

2011 MacBook Pro may need a firmware update in order to do this. Refer to "[Computers that can be upgraded to use OS X Internet Recovery](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4904)" and click on the link for your specific computer model to find a download and instructions.

*Far too much info on the above links to even attempt to make a good answer in here.*

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, I don't think I can install the update because, like I said, I wiped the HD. Is there some way to apply the update without OSX? When I connect to WiFi and enter his Apple ID, I get an error message telling me to try again later.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access to Lion with your AppleID, because the previous owner of this MacBook forgot to "deauthorize" it before selling.
(Forgive me this meaningless and stupid term, a more appropriate term would have been "revoke ownership").